# ClickOnce não recebe ultima atualização

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, clickonce

Tenho uma aplicaçao em WinForms, publicada em meu servidor de app.

Quando tento instalar a ultima versão ex. 1.1 pelo ClickOnce, a maquina do cliente faz a instalação da versão 1.0, que no caso é a versão atualmente instalada na maquina do cliente.

Esse caso esta acontecendo em algumas maquinas a cada 30, duas acontecem esse caso.

Obs.: Minha aplicação força o cliente instalar a ultima versao publicada, porem nesse caso, nao esta acontecendo.

Answer (score 0):

Na empresa onde trabalho acontece o mesmo problema, identificamos que era o proxy que causava esse problema. Somente nas máquinas com o proxy que acontecia isso.

Desative o proxy e instale a nova versão, reative o proxy, foi o que resolveu o problema até o momento. 
Estamos também procurando uma solução definitiva para este problema.

Caso já tenha achado uma solução definitiva, por favor compartilhe.